# How to detect keyboard language?

Tags: java, events, keyboard, focus

For a (NetBeans) GUI in Java language below,

[image]

I want keyboard input language mode be automatically changed -

to Korean when the "K Box" gets focus (i.e., cursor is in "K Box"),

to English When the "E Box" gets focus (i.e., cursor is in "E Box")

(FYI, keyboard input language mode is changed by hitting right-ALT key).

If that is not going to be possible, I want to detect whether it is in English input mode or in Korean input mode.  Then I'll make a label telling current input language mode to the users so they don't need to make mistake typing Korean in English mode.

Comment: You have `user.country` and `user.language` properties. (Look at `System.getProperty()`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès is this what Swing uses?  I would expect that eventually the operating system settings are in play.

Comment: The results as following :
  System.getProperty("user.language") -> ko,
  System.getProperty("user.country") -> KR. 
Strangely, the keyboard is in English mode until I press right-Alt key.

Comment: If keyboard is not compliant with system locale then use `InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();`  `System.out.println(context.getLocale().getDisplayLanguage());` `System.out.println(context.getLocale().getLanguage());` that should work.

Comment: Why don't you use only one textfield? Two textfields for the same data is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I defined following method and using it to change keyboard language for a specific component. In the code 'ControlEnums.Languages' is my own enum type, so you may ignore it for the moment.

```
public static void setKeyboardLanguage(Component comp, 
    ControlEnums.Languages language) 
{
    try {
        InputContext inCtx  =  comp.getInputContext();
        Character.Subset[] subset = new Character.Subset[1];

        if (language == KOREAN) {
            // for Korean input mode
            subset[0] = Character.UnicodeBlock.HANGUL_SYLLABLES;
        } else {
            // for English input mode
            subset = null;
        }
        inCtx.setCharacterSubsets(subset);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I found the above method 'setKeyboardLanguage' works pretty well. Does anyone have a better idea on my research?